# Bijective Proof: Number of Partitions of 2n into n parts

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

The number of partitions of n is equal to the # of the partitions of 2n divided into n parts.

I know that the number of partitions of any integer n into i parts equals the number of partitions of n with the largest part i, but do not know where to go from here, especially how to prove via bijection - any help is appreciated!

(Supp. problem in my intro. combinatorics class)

Answer (score 10):

HINT: Let $\pi$ be a partition of $2n$ into $n$ parts. Throw away one element from each part of $\pi$, and you get a partition of $n$.

Comment: Wow much simpler than what I was thinking of doing. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user63101: You’re very welcome.

Comment: This is awesome! This is so simple! :) By any chance in which book can i read it?